# Is there less blue light available because the sky is blue?

Tags: physics, color

Are the things we see that are blue .... less blue during daytime because the sky is blue (less blue light available to eluminate the ground)?

Comment: Relevance to space exploration?

Answer (score 4):

The only thing we see that is less blue due to the sky being blue is... the Sun!  As well as things directly illuminated by the Sun.

Light from the Sun reaches us directly or indirectly.  The sky usually looks either blue (in absence of clouds), white/grey (in presence of clouds), or reddish (near sunset)¹.  In most cases, much of this light merges again (except the part scattering or reflected back into space), so we don't see everyday objects being less blue, although objects in direct sunlight do look yellowish or reddish, and therefore less blue.

However, if we look at the Sun, it is less blue; in fact, it looks rather yellow-ish, more yellow than it would if you were outside the atmosphere.  The blue light has been scattered out by Rayleigh scattering, forming the blue sky.

---

¹Why is "why is the sky blue" a more popular question than "why is the sky grey/white", when in many parts of the world grey/white skies are more common?

Comment: Regarding the first sentence: Actually... the front-side of a lit object gets less blue as well, because it receives only half of the skies blue. But the backside sees a lot more blue than it would without the sky. (yes, you put this in the second paragraph, but maybe you could phrase it a bit more explicitly)

Comment: The answer to your last question may be historical -- they sky was probably less grey before industrialization.

Comment: @Barmar Was it?  Typically around 70% of the Earth is covered in clouds.

Comment: Unless it's overcast, there's often plenty of blue sky between the clouds. Average cloud cover over land is currently about 54%.

Comment: At 54%, there's more grey sky than blue sky, and yet "why is the sky blue" is a much more common question than "why is the sky grey".  Apparently, for many, "because it's cloudy" is a satisfactory answer to "why is the sky grey", but why are the clouds grey and not blue or yellow? :-)

Comment: @gerrit Intuitively speaking: Clouds are *things*. Things have colours. Sky is air. Air doesn't have colour. Of course that isn't entirely accurate, but that's what our intuition says. So the sky having a colour is much less intuitive than clouds having colours.

Comment: @gerrit gray and white are neutral colors, thus rather mundane, so don't make one wonder. And the sky is not only blue: it's a wide-FoV smooth blue-to-white gradient that most people find aesthetically pleasing, and this, in addition to the colors being far from neutral, is what triggers such questions.

Comment: _"In most cases, this light merges again"_ — strictly speaking, not all light merges back. This is easy to figure if we notice that the Earth as viewed from space is blue. And this blue is indeed due to Rayleigh scattering (although some of bluing comes from the ocean). So there's a net loss of blue part of sunlight spectrum to space, rendering the objects on the ground receiving less of it.

Comment: @Ruslan Fair point.  I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**When you watch a red sunset, the people living west of you admire their blue sky.**

More scattering happens when the light takes a longer path through the atmosphere. During daytime, the light that hits the surface goes almost straight through, and not much filtering happens. Blue sky gets its light from rays that go almost parallel to the surface and hit ground beyond your horizon.

[image: Illustration of light ray path during daytime and sunset]

<sup>(Image: own drawings on top of Google Maps screenshot)</sup>